# npm private registry username with special characters

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to access a private npm registry that is hosted in a remote server. I have to access it using username and password. There is no proxy on my side.

But, the username and password which I use, have URL unsafe characters. I've tried `adduser`, `npmjs`, `scl` but I'm unable to configure the credentials :

```
npm WARN Name may not contain non-url-safe chars
```

I've tried to set `NPM_USER` and `NPM_PASS` directly from command line. I'm able to set the former but the later fails. Even if I use a simple password and try :

```
npm login
```

It fails with the same error since `NPM_USER` has a `@`

I'm using `npmrc` to switch between public and private registries. I want to avoid tools like `Nexus/JFrog`.

> npm version - 4.0.5 and OS is Windows 7

What am I missing here?

Comment: It might be an issue with your npm private repo having username with the '@' sign. It is an npm plugin for another system?

Answer (score 18):

So to recap, your problem is that your private registry uses email addresses for user names, which is not currently supported by the npm command line tools. You need a way to provide your user name without running `npm adduser` or `npm login`. I don't know which registry you are using, but I had the same problem with [Inedo's Proget](https://inedo.com/proget).

*EDIT: I have the same problem in March 2021, with [Azure Artifacts in Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/artifacts/), because the npm command-line tools still don't allow `@` in usernames, and also the `vsts-npm-auth` command-line tool [does not work on Linux or Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops). I have also had the same problem with Artifactory.*

If you're using a private registry and you are using scopes to separate the different registries, you can create an `.npmrc` file that looks like this:

```sh
#Settings for @SCOPENAME
@SCOPENAME:registry=https://DOMAIN/FEED/
//DOMAIN/FEED/:username=USER@DOMAIN
//DOMAIN/FEED/:_password=BASE64(PASSWORD)
//DOMAIN/FEED/:email=EMAIL_ADDRESS
//DOMAIN/FEED/:always-auth=true

#Settings for @OTHERSCOPENAME
@OTHERSCOPENAME:registry=...
```

This next bit might be important, but it depends on your registry's preferred feed urls: I couldn't get this to work properly without the trailing `/` so take care to try both with and without it.

An easy way to get the base64 encoding of your password is to run:

```
echo -n 'PASSWORD' | base64
```

*EDIT: For some registries, like [Azure Artifacts](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/artifacts/), you need to use a **personal access token** instead of your normal password. Look up the instructions for your registry about how to create a token.*

*EDIT: It's also possible to have the `.npmrc` file without scopes, if you are only using one registry:*

```sh
# Global settings
registry=https://DOMAIN/FEED/
//DOMAIN/FEED/:username=USER@DOMAIN
//DOMAIN/FEED/:_password=BASE64(PASSWORD)
//DOMAIN/FEED/:email=EMAIL_ADDRESS
//DOMAIN/FEED/:always-auth=true
```

Comment: Should always-auto be always-auth?

Comment: I missed initially that the later lines should not have the https prefix - if this is still not working for you, check that.

Answer (score -4):

You just have to login normally without the '@'.  Unfortunately its kind of hard to find this information on npm.  When you publish packages is when you need to use the @ symbol.

If this is for a public organization and for example I have an organization name "@seatbelt" so a package name I publish under is "@seatbelt/core".  The package is installed by typing "npm install @seatbelt/core".

If this is just for you personally to publish private packages you publish  private package names with the format "@username/project-name".  Like the example above, once published you can install the package by doing "npm install @username/project-name"

More information can be found at https://docs.npmjs.com/private-modules/intro

Comment: This isn't a problem with the package scope, it's a problem with `npm login` not accepting email addresses as usernames since it won't allow `@` as a character in a username.